# Can We send mail through postfix installed on another server

Tags: postfix-mta

I have a question related to `postfix`.

I have two servers say `server1` and `server2`. For some reasons my `server1`  is unabled to send mail through `postfix`. Now I want to send configure `server 2` such that I can send mail from `server1` via `server2`.

How it can be possible ? Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use (within *main.cf* on server1) server2 as **relayhost**.